# Getting rid of warning in a Spring Boot project being migrated to the Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am migrating certain Gradle project from the Groovy to the Kotlin DSL.

I am using the [kotlin-dsl](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin) plugin and configuring Spring Boot as follows:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot").version(Versions.springBootVersion)
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

The documentation of the `kotlin-dsl` plugin asks to **not** specify any specific Kotlin version, as quoted below:

> Avoid specifying a version for the kotlin-dsl plugin:
>
> Each Gradle release is meant to be used with a specific version of the
>   kotlin-dsl plugin and compatibility between arbitrary Gradle releases
>   and kotlin-dsl plugin versions is not guaranteed. Using an unexpected
>   version of the kotlin-dsl plugin in a build will emit a warning and
>   can cause hard to diagnose problems.

And this is my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class App {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runApplication<App>(*args)
    }
}
```

Under the line starting with `class App` I see a warning in IntelliJ that tells me:

```
Classes annotated with '@Configuration' could be implicitly subclassed and must not be final
```

I know this is because the `App` class should be declared as `open`. 
To the best of my knowledge the Gradle Spring Boot plugin for Kotlin should be in charge of making an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class `open` for me behind the curtains. So I tried adding the following plugin:

`kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"`

(where `version "1.3.72"` corresponds to the Kotlin version)

And the exception is gone, as expected.
However, this approach is against the recommended guideline of not hard-coding the Kotlin version in the Gradle configuration.

What are the best practices for configuring Spring Boot using the Kotlin DSL so I do not have to hard-code the Kotlin version in my build script ? 
Maybe there is a way to get rid of the warning in IntelliJ without having to add the `kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"` plugin ?
I think this may be an IntelliJ specific issue since I do not see any similar warning when building or executing the project with gradle from a terminal even if the `kotlin("plugin.spring")` is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gradle user guide for the [Kotlin DSL Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin) describes it like this:

> The Kotlin DSL Plugin provides a convenient way to develop Kotlin-based projects that contribute build logic. That includes buildSrc projects, included builds and Gradle plugins.

Your Spring Boot application does not contribute build logic and you probably shouldn't be using the plugin for it. If you were developing a Gradle plugin in Kotlin, then it would make more sense. And in that case you should be working against the same version of the Gradle API for the Kotlin DSL that is provided by the version you are building with, as targeting another version can be a bit tricky.

I would remove the plugin and instead be explicit about your configuration. You will need to put a few more lines in your build files, but this way the complication classpath won't be polluted by the DSL stuff that you don't need anyway.

It also means you need to hard-code the Kotlin version, but this is a good thing as you would otherwise rely on whatever happens to be included in the version of Gradle you are building with.

For example:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.0.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE"))
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
}
```